# Problems turning on or restarting Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: grub2, kernel

A few days ago I updated the repositories and since the date it does not start normally, I have to access the grub, choose a kernel and I can just start.

Ubuntu does not start in normal mode, I have to access the grub and choose the kernel version to start, in this case only 5.4.0-31-generic, otherwise it never starts the OS.

[image: The selected kernel is the only thing that works.]

[image: What it shows after choosing linux 5.4.0-35]

Answer (score 0):

1. can you tell, what kind of update you made? Was is 18.04 to 20.04?
2. What kind of hardware do you use?
3. Whats your setup (single boot or multiboot with Windows)?
4. Legacy Bois or UEFI? If UEFI, try Legacy
5. TPM 1.2 or TPM 2.0 activated? If yes, try to disable it
6. is your BOIS version update2date?

Maybe this [Links here can help you](https://dellwindowsreinstallationguide.com/ubuntu-20-04/)

Comment: After executing these commands I had the problems
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade, 
 I have version 20.04 LTS, On the computer I only have ubuntu without another OS

Comment: @BekoPonce and whats your hardware?